# Graph shows over reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[image]

Why does the reputation graph under your user account "Reputation" section show bars that go above the daily reputation cap of +200? Is it just the potential rep cap (what you would have earned had they not capped it)? If so that seems a bit counter-intuitive, it should represent the actual rep earned on those days.

Note: I just realized cursors aren't in screencaps, this is pointing to the tallest bar, the bar 3 place to the left of that one is at the 200 cap mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can earn more than 200 points a day.  The 200 rep cap is only the rep cap for upvotes, but does not include bounties, or accepted answer points.  The bar serves as a reference for the rep cap, and is fairly useful in that role.

Comment: Ohh that makes more sense I never realized that cap was only for updates. Thanks.